# Vlookup Range using the last value in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to use the range to lookup with a defined variable that has the last row value of every sheet but it doesn't return anything

```
    For N2 = 1 To 15
    Dim cell3 As String
    cell3 = Range("B3").End(xlDown).Value
    Range("C3").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(cell3,'" & N2 & "'!$B$4:$AH$35,MATCH(C3,'" & N2 & "'!$B$3:$AH$3,0),FALSE)"
    Next N2
```

Thanks

Comment: I'll look into this a bit deeper but your formula should be put into the `Selection`, not the `ActiveCell`. There is only one [Activecell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738%28v=office.11%29.aspx) in a selection.

Comment: The problem is that is not recognizing the cell3 = Range("B3").End(xlDown).Value

Answer (score 0):

You are making a selection of a number of cells but only putting the formula into the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738%28v=office.11%29.aspx) of that selection. A selection can be any number of calls from 1 to the entire worksheet but there is always only 1 activecell in that selection.

```
Dim n2 As Long, cell3 As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    For n2 = 1 To 15
        cell3 = .Range("B3").End(xlDown).Value
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(3, 3).End(xlDown))
            .Formula = _
                "=VLOOKUP(" & chr(34) & cell3 & chr(34) & ", '" & n2 & "'!$B$4:$AH$35, MATCH(C3,'" & n2 & "'!$B$3:$AH$3, 0), FALSE)"
        End With
    Next n2
End With
```

As far as the use of `n2` is concerned, are your worksheets named 2, 3, 4, etc or should you be returning the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) using `n2` as the [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx)? A possible alternate formula would be,

```
            .Formula = _
                "=VLOOKUP(" & chr(34) & cell3 & chr(34) & ", '" & worksheets(n2).name & "'!$B$4:$AH$35, MATCH(C3,'" & worksheets(n2).name & "'!$B$3:$AH$3, 0), FALSE)"
```

That uses `n2` as the ordinal index to retrieve the worksheet name.

Comment: @maxwell - If `cell3` is returning a number or date then the above should do. If it is returning text then you will have to add quotes to the formula.

Comment: I dit it like this " & cell3 & " but still doesn't return a value it shows #NAME error and if I add aphostrophe ' " & cell3 & " ' it sends me 1004 error.

Comment: OK, it seems that `cell3` contains a string; not a date or number. See the modification(s) above. ASCII character 034 is the quote character. You needed to quote the string you were stuffing in just as you would have to quote a string you were typing into the worksheet formula. I've used `Chr(34)` because I hate having to deal with doubling up quote characters within quoted strings.

Comment: Yes it worked, you're amazing @Jeeped thanks for replying my silly questions ejej.Regards!

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi, as I was running the macro I realized that the lookup range is the value of the last cell but I want the lookup range to be cell rather than the value. Could you please tell me how to change it? I've tried without results haha